# How do I move (sweep, export) my private keys from my Electrum standard wallet to a new HD wallet using Electrum?

Tags: electrum, bip32-hd-wallets, mnemonic-seed, private-key-export

My present  wallet which I have been using to accumulate BTC (50+ utxos) is a Electrum Standard, script type is p2pkh, with seed available and the keystore type is bip32. I assume that I should now move all private keys and history to my new hardware wallet which is a Electrum Standard wallet with script type p2wpkh with no seed (except the Satochip settings show the hd wallet is seeded) bip32 and a keystore type HD (Satochip). What are the steps to safely transition to my new hardware wallet? I received this answer from Satochip.io regarding this issue which I don't fully understand.
"Regarding your software wallet, if you have an Electrum Seed (non BIP39), you won’t be able to recover your information from to SW to the HW. In this case, you should send all your Bitcoin from one adress to the Hw one. If your SW seed is BIP39, you can import it to your Satochip HW and will have access to all your wallet information."
Thanks for any clarity you can provide!

Answer (score 1):

Just send your bitcoins to an address in the HW.

Answer (score 0):

You can export your private keys by going to the Wallet menu and selecting "Private keys" > "Export". Then, you can import your private keys into your new HD wallet by going to the "Wallet" menu and selecting "Private keys" > "Import".

Comment: My Electrum HD wallet (standard) under "Wallet" menu the 2 choices are Sweep and Export  and Export is grayed out.